# becomeFirstResponder sometimes does not open the keyboard on ios 10

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, touch-id, becomefirstresponder

I'm creating an native touch id alert with code:

```
    let context = LAContext()

    guard deviceCanUseTouchId(context: context) else {
        return
    }

    presentingAlert = true
    [context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "touch_id_auth_message".localized(), reply: { [unowned self] success, error -> Void in
        self.presentingAlert = false
        self.canPresentAlert = true

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {    
            completionHandler?(success)
        }
    })]
```

button handler that calls the native Touch ID alert looks like this:

```
@IBAction func touchUpInsideUseTouchIdButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    ACTouchId.sharedManager.authenticateWithTouchId(completionHandler: { [weak self] in
        self?.handleTouchIdAuthentication(granted: $0)
        })

    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

and this is the code of handleTouchIdAuthentication:

```
private func handleTouchIdAuthentication(granted granted: Bool) {
    if granted {
        //...
    } else {
        passcodeDigitTextField1.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

The problem is, that most of the time, when I cancel the Touch ID native dialog, the alert dismiss correctly and becomeFirstResponder() works OK.

However at around 1 in 10 times, becomeFirstResponder() returns true, passcodeDigitTextField1 gets focus, but the keyboard does not appear. Moreover keyboard will not show itself even if I change the focus to other text field by tapping them.

Strangly, this works fine for ios 9 and 8. **The issue happens only on iOS 10**.

Comment: Can you do that piece in main thread?

Comment: Are you using simulator or Actual device?

Comment: I'm using actual device with iOS 10.0.2.

Comment: the handleTouchIdAuthentication method is actually dispatched to the main queue (see that completion handler code is dispatch in the first snippet)

Answer (score 2):

As Rajan mentioned:

> Just a hack. Can you just do
>   passcodeDigitTextField1.becomeFirstResponder() in a function and call
>   that function with a delay of 0.25 or 0.5 seconds using
>   performSelector and tell the result –

This worked, I ended up with 0.01 delay

I will not mark this answer as this is only a workaround.

Comment: I also faced same issue in iOS 10.2 . Using this workaround somehow fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me every time in exactly the same situation, trying to set field focus after a failed Touch ID authentication. I solved it by subscribing to [UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdidbecomeactivenotification) on the default NSNotificationCenter and putting my call to `becomeFirstResponder` inside that.

ApplicationDidBecomeActive fires slightly *after* the Touch ID callback, which might explain the problem.

It's slightly more awkward to code for but it's working 100% of the time so far. Way better than performSelector.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try doing this. Not Sure it will work!

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      passcodeDigitTextField1.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: I did with classic GCD dispatch_async. It didn't help.
We are using swift2 ATM

Comment: Just a hack. Can you just do `passcodeDigitTextField1.becomeFirstResponder()` in a function and call that function with a delay of 0.25 or 0.5 seconds using performSelector and tell the result

Comment: 0.25 Seems to did a good work, as I was not able to reproduce this issue with this. Will try to fine-tune this number at Wednesday as, the holidays came.

There is one more problem with this. On iOS 10 in contrary to 9 and 8 this becomeFirstResponder even without the 0.25 delay apply focus on the control after around 1 second which is a noticeably crappy user experience, additional 0.25 second does not make it better :/

Comment: @Dzior We can have OS version checks here. Don't do delay in 9 and 8

Comment: Still, this is only a really bad hack, and user experience for 10 is bad ATM

Answer (score 0):

It might sound really stupid but... in my case once it helped to restart the whole device. Just that. It was also iOS 10 only.
;) Maybe there is someone with a similar problem out there and did not try that before checking stack overflow since it seems kind of weird to just restart the device for an error like this.